# How can I tell if a page is being served to an iframe?

Tags: iframe

I took the src url of an iframe containing a google map, and tried to load it in my browser, but I got this response instead:

```
The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.
```

Try it for yourself: [link](https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3151.0229065372178!2d144.9692174!3d-37.8363496!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x6ad66803a3e7f505%3A0x4473d6750f436b9c!2s5%2F150+Albert+Rd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1393546734431)

How does it know that the page is being loaded in a browser, rather than a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (window==window.top) { /* I'm not in an iframe */ }
```

Very simple javascript.